# File read loop with early exit

Tags: ruby, loops, file-io

I have to deal with some unwieldy files in Ruby. Given a particular ID, I know the data associated with the ID will be in *not more than one* of the files, but I'm not sure which one. It may also be absent, which is an error state I need to handle. So I have a loop like this:

```
files = ['a','b','c','d']
files.each do |filename|
  File.open(filename,'r') do |f|
    break unless contains_id(myid)
    do_stuff
  end
end
```

So I have two questions:

1. What's the right way to break out of the loop once I've found the file that contains the data I'm looking for?
2. How can I deal with the situation where the data is not in any file?

This is what I came up with but it feels rough:

```
files = ['a','b','c','d']
found = false
files.each do |filename|
  break if found
  File.open(filename,'r') do |f|
    break unless contains_id(myid)
    found = true
    do_stuff
  end
end
do_error_stuff unless found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable#find` instead of `#each` to find the first entry in `files` for which the block returns true, or else `nil`. So this would look like:

```
files = ['a','b','c','d']
file = files.find do |filename|
  File.open(filename,'r') do |f|
    contains_id(myid)
  end
end
do_error_stuff unless file
```